# How to write a python function that can be used with pandas method chaining

Tags: python, pandas, function, methods, chaining

This is my initial approach:

```py
In [91]: def f(dataframe,col):
    ...:     dataframe[col] = dataframe[col]*0
```

But this failed with the following:

```py
In [90]: df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[4,5]})

In [91]: def f(dataframe,col):
    ...:     dataframe[col] = dataframe[col]*0
    ...:

In [92]: df.f('a')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-e1a104c6b712> in <module>
----> 1 df.f('a')

~/.virtualenvs/this-env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5177             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5178                 return self[name]
-> 5179             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5180
   5181     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'f'
```

I assumed that this would be fairly well documented, but I can't an example anywhere.

Comment: What you are trying to do is monkey-patch in a new method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is called monkey-patching.  You need to write the function as a method (it will have `self` as the first parameter) and then assign the method as an attribute to `pd.DataFrame` **class**, not the instantiated object.

```
import pandas as pd

def f(self, col):
    self.loc[:, col] = self.loc[:, col] * 0
    return self

pd.DataFrame.f = f

df=pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2],'b':[4,5]})
df.f('a')
# returns:
   a  b
0  0  4
1  0  5
```

Keep in mind that your method as-written will modify the dataframe in-place.  If you need to preserve the original dataframe, use `.copy` at the top of your function.